# How to serialise in rest assured , java keywords

Tags: java, automation, rest-assured, pojo

I'm testing API with rest assured programming language is JAVA, I'm facing an issue with serialising JSON payload to java object.
I have a following JSON payload:

```
{
  "orderId": "Ybpv82lJ", 
  "total": "5",
  "currencyId": "Belm3pnb",
  "localCurrencyRate": 1,
  "for": "2218",
  "recipientName": "new Order",
  "numberOfPayments": 1,
  "holderFullName": "Name ",
  "holderIdNumber": "123456",
  "lastFourDigits": "4544",
  "timezone": 360
}
```

as u can see in above JSON payload , I have a java reserved keyword **for**
so when I'm creating my POJO class , I'm facing the issue
, I have the following POJO class

```
@Data
public class CardReceiptRoot {
    public Integer localCurrencyRate;
    private String for;                     // this is where I'm facing the issue
    private String orderId;
    private String currencyId;
    private String total;
    private String recipientName;
    private Integer numberOfPayments;
    private String holderFullName;
    private String holderIdNumber;
    private String lastFourDigits;
    private Integer timezone;
}
```

**how can I deal with it , pls help me if u have any ideas , thanks in advance !**

Comment: Have you checked the object mapping section from RestAssured docs, this may help https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#object-mapping

Answer (score 0):

This solution might help you:

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
...
@JsonProperty("for")
private String forId;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , I have to clarify something , should I add this library to pom.xml   `import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;` , or i have to create as intellij idea suggesting to create a jsonProperty class?

Comment: It's jackson annotation.